Background task in react-native
We have a react-native app. We need to track geo-location in the background and to send it to server every 10 seconds. We are not able to find how to get started with something which can help us do action every 10 second in the background.
We have tried with "Headless JS" and "react-native-background-fetch" but our app does not work. We are looking for someone who has already solved this problem successfully.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

For running things into the background, i would suggest using the following

AppState

It is a package from React-Native self and provides the functionality to do certain actions when the application is entering a background | inactive state.
